# Определяем POP3 сервер по email

Tags: pop3, php, email

Дан *email* вида **name@domain.zone**.
Необходимо определить сервер входящей почты (адрес и порт) для чтения письма. Желательно определить имя пользователя.

Пример:
Для `name@mail.ru` должен выдать `pop.mail.ru:110 username:name`
Для `name@ekotek.info` должен выдать `mail.ekotek.info:110 username name+ekotek.info`

Для последнего можно не проверять. Привел только ради того, чтобы показать что имена для почтовых адресов берутся не до символа @. И ставлю под сомнение, что это вообще возможно для последнего (определение имени).

НО: Домен прекрасно определяет служба Gmail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что идёт перебор распространённых наименований (pop, pop3, mail, relay и т.д.) с проверкой по 110 порту.

Comment: Такой вариант тоже сразу пришел в голову. Но думаю, еще есть возможность опросить сервисы у домена... Вот как и что это даст?)

Comment: Ну на сколько мне известно можно определить MX запись домена,а она должна совпадать с smtp...Есть доля вероятности что это же будет pop3))))

Comment: Абсолютно точно. Я определял по MX домену, а далее вручную, перебором.